# VMware - Workstation 9

Tags: virtual-machine, 64-bit, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I'm trying to install windows server 2012 on my "VMware 9.0 32 bit app" and it gives me an error that It can not install any 64 bit software

I am using a Dell 3521 laptop and I have Windows 8.1 64 bit on the host.
Is this because my processor could be a logical 64 bit not physical 64 bit or what?

Comment: If you have a 32 bit VMWare it's not surprising you cannot install 64 bits software into it...

Comment: I did it before on an HP pavilion dv6 1390 Laptop with the same VMware :D

Comment: If you have a 64-bit Windows 8.1 installed as a host operating system of course you have a 64-bit processor. **If you didn't have 64-bit processor, then you wouldn't have a 64-bit operating system, installed as the host operating system.be possible.**  Have you enabled virtualization technology within your BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: yes I did and I'm surprised because I'm using the Hyper-V and I had already installed the windows server 2012 on it 
what do you think :D ?

Answer (score 0):

From what it sounds like, although you have a 64-bit processor, it lacks hardware virtualization and therefore you cannot have 64-bit guests virtualized. This is the `VT-x` technology that most budget processors (as that laptop has) lack.

To verify, plug in your processor's model into [this](http://ark.intel.com/) site and it'll tell you more.